# Avoid duplicates after certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to report on how many costumers we have on certain products. The data I can get are correspondence with the costumers, but for every new e-mail is a new activity. Therefore, I can not just use the Pivot and count the number of addresses. I currently have a code to avoid any duplicates which is

`=IF(COUNTIF($D$2:D2;B3)>0;"";B3)`

The problem with that code is, that if we have a correspondence with the same costumer on two different products, they are only displayed the first time they appear. Here is an example:

[image: Example]

I want the Adr Nr formatted cells to display the Adr Nr when it appears the first time for every object/product. That would mean 1,1,2,Empty,3,Empty,4,Empty.
(Cell D8 isn't displaying 4 because the formula isn't pulled to the cell yet)

I hope you can solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. See the sample data below.

[image]

The formula in F3 is

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C3&D3,CONCATENATE($C$2:C2&$D$2:D2),0)),"",D3)
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an array formula. The formula shall be automatically enclosed in curly braces to indicate that this is an Array Formula. This solution will not work if you do not create an array formula.

Select and drag it down up to the intended rows.

Replace comma with semi colon in the formula since that appears to be the list separator in your case.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you very much. I've just tested it, and everything seems to be working. I have never seen the 'Concatenate' function before, I can see how it's quite useful in this situation. Thank you!